# Can you edit Javascript values using firebug, to make the JS run ajax to call php file if value > 5

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm thinking about using ajax to call a php file once a javascript variable reaches a certain amount. Just a bit worried about a possible exploit. Say I had a JS variable which would add 1 upon a button click and once that variable reached 5 (5x button clicks), the ajax would be called. Would it be possible to alter the JS in say firebug and call the ajax without needing the 5x button presses? Any other threats I should consider?

Yes I'm aware a user could just look at the source and see the php file to be called, I've added security measures here.

Comment: if the said counter is in an closure the browser dev tool (firebug or other) should not be able to access/modifies it's value

Comment: The simple answer is: once code is off of your server and delivered to the browser, it's out of your hands, and you should assume that anything is possible. In your case, an attacker could simply watch network traffic that happens after 5 button clicks, copy the resulting AJAX call, and replay it from cURL, for example, without even being in a browser. Lots of other opportunities for attack, so make sure you're doing solid server-side validation.